# Coonection is Refused In JBoss Cluster

Tags: jboss, load-balancing

A new connection is getting refused by some JBoss nodes in my cluster when the load is increased. But when I look at the CPU/Memory usage of these nodes they are just at minimal level not beyond 10% CPU usage and 60% of Memory Usage. I don't understand what else is causing the connections to be refused. In some cases the connection are getting refused at load balancer itself before it is going to any node. There is no network latency as well. The entire environment is under LAN. The below is the error message.

```
 Unable to connect to server. Error attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. Typically, the server is down or cannot open more sockets on its system. If the error detail is "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect" for all requests, it typically means that the Load Generator is using an inappropriate network interface. Details: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect 
Please refer to the documentation for further details and advice
```

Comment: Any idea? I am using Jboss 5.1

Comment: Several JBoss nodes are refusing the connections after reaching around 300 users.